# Is it better to have multiple nested classes with the same dependency or one with a larger scope?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

In my Spring boot app i'm creating a Factory for creating different objects with the same interface and dependency like below.

```
@Component
public class FarmFactory {

    @Autowired
    private FarmRepo farmRepo;

    public IFarm create(FarmType type) {
        if (type == type.APPLE) {
            return new AppleFarm(farmRepo);
        } else if (type == type.ANIMAL) {
            return new AnimalFarm(farmRepo);
        } else {
            return new EmptyFarm(farmRepo);
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering if it was better to limit the scope the FarmRepo dependency by instead injecting it into each subclass of farm (apple, animal, empty). Or if it was better to keep a single dependency in a higher scope of the Factory.

Alternatively the dependency FarmRepo could be passed into the create method with the type, but not sure what the rule of thumb is for dependency scope.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, a good design can reduce `if-else` as much as possible. So I prefer to injecting it into each subclass in your case. Thus in future, you have more flexibility if the dependency also have subclass as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create named beans of your real implementations (AppleFarm, AnimalFarm ..) and inject the FarmRepo. With you factory your real implementations won't be managed by Spring (no beans).

```
@Component("appleFarm")
@RequiredArgsConstructor <- this is a Lombok feature check it out
public class AppleFarm implements Farm {

private final FarmRepo repo;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your IFarm implementations are model classes. It is not a good practise to have a repository inside a model. You should consider to move the creation of different IFarm implementations to the FarmRepo.

If IFarm implementations are some sort of service classes that governs business logic then you should let spring handle it injecting the FarmRepo instance to them. In that case you better consider having an abstract class rather than using IFarm, because FarmRepo is a common dependency among them.

There is nothing wrong in employing a simple factory method to instantiate the required runtime type, if that's required, it needs to be done somewhere, it helps you gain a valid design in terms of OCP (open close principle) preventing you to change bahaviour depending on type parameter, rather you make use of polymorphism.